# ActiveRecord saves nothing but nil attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm using Rails 4.2.4 and Ruby 2.3.1 on the production environments.
Sometimes when saving has_many relationships the records are saved to the database with all attributes set to nil. I'm having trouble reproducing this in local environment but it happens often on the production env.

```
class Transaction
  has_many :transaction_lines, foreign_key: "transaction_id", autosave: false
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :transaction_lines
end

class TransactionLine
  belongs_to :entry, :foreign_key => 'transaction_id', :class_name => 'Transaction'
end
```

Here is the example of the saved attributes:

[image]

Comment: Why you not adding rails validation like `validates :product_id, presence: true` validation for all attributes

Comment: well I will try adding the validation and see how things goes, but I already validates a lot of business logic that depends on the presence attributes, and i have also retry using the same exact request but was not able to reproduce the results.

Comment: The validation makes sure data exists or not if data exists then he will save otherwise not, but you need to make sure how data passing and why not passing the data sometimes. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html

Comment: could be race conditions in production. Are you running multithreaded server? Is your code thread safe? Is anything happening inside ActiveRecord transactions?  Check pool size as well.

Comment: @lacostenycoder it is running on multithreaded server with high load (might be to the same records).

Answer (score 1):

**has_many(name, scope = nil, options = {}, &extension)**

...

**:autosave**

If true, always save the associated objects or destroy them if marked for destruction, when saving the parent object. If false, never save or destroy the associated objects. By default, only save associated objects that are new records. This option is implemented as a before_save callback. Because callbacks are run in the order they are defined, associated objects may need to be explicitly saved in any user-defined before_save callbacks.

**Note that accepts_nested_attributes_for sets :autosave to true.**

ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods